# How can I use Perl to incrementally print a string?

Tags: perl, substring, substr

```
my $line2 = ("My cat Garfield");
my $leng2 = length $line2;
my $longmatch;
my $post = 0;
my $letter = 1; 

for(my $post = 0; $post < $leng2; $post++) {
    for($letter = 1; $letter <= $leng2; $letter++) {
        $longmatch = (substr($line2,$post,$letter));
        print $longmatch,  "\n";    
    }   
}
```

How can I eliminate the repeated lines??

Comment: Do you want to print several lines, each one longer than the previous or print the string one character at a time (slowly)? Post your code, it will be easier to understand...

Answer (score 6):

Using C-style loops -- `for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)` -- is not the perl way. Simply use `for my $i (0 .. 10)` instead.

In this example, I use the implicit variable `$_` in a post-script loop, and use [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) instead of print to get the automatic newline ending:

```
use v5.10; # used to enable feature say
my $cat = 'my cat is Garfield'; 
say substr($cat, 0, $_) for 1 .. length($cat);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your substr() arguments are probably wrong.

```
my $x = "my cat is Garfield";
for (my $i = 1; $i <= length($x); $i++) {
    print substr($x, 0, $i) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $a= 'my cat is Garfield';

for(my$i = 0; $i <= length($a); ++$i)
{
    printf("%.*s\n", $i, $a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print substr( $str, 0, $_ ), "\n" foreach 1..( length $str );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming when you say "How can I eliminate the repeated lines??", you mean "eliminate the lines that look the same as the previous line because they have a trailing space" the following may do what you want. Please note I have shamelessly copied a previous contribution in a sad attempt to get awarded an answer :)

```
use v5.10; # used to enable feature say

my $cat = 'my cat is Garfield';
my $last = "";

for (1 .. length($cat) ){
    my $text = substr($cat, 0, $_);

    my $trim = $text;
    $trim =~ s/\s+$//;

    say $trim unless ($trim eq $last);
    $last = $trim;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
my $a = "your string";
map { print substr($a, 0, $_) . "\n" } (1..length($a));
```

Comment: Avoid using `map` in void context (that's what `for` loops are for)

Comment: @Zaid Works with `grep` too: `grep { say substr($a, 0, $_) }`  =)

Comment: @TLP : Let's not give people funny ideas :|

Comment: @Zaid Thanks for pointing that out. Calling map in void context is sloppy programming.